# Inline enumerate: Two lines are not aligned

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem, inline

I tried to make a horizontal list using `\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}`. However, when it breaks into new line, the second line is not aligned the same as the first one.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{
    label = \textbf{\arabic*.},
    align = left,
    labelwidth = \parindent, 
    leftmargin = \parindent,
    style = standard
}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate*}[mode = unboxed, itemjoin = \hspace{2cm}]
    \item text
    \item text
    \item text
    \item text
    \item text
    \item text
    \item text
    \item text
    \item text
    \item text
\end{enumerate*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I've known that there is `tasks` environment, but somehow it's not suitable for my work.

Comment: Does adding `\noindent` before `\begin{enumerate*}` do what you want? **Edit:** it seems to help (by moving "1." to the left) but doesn't adress the alignment issue.

Comment: thank you, I've just tried that one, and yes, 2 line are still not well aligned.

Answer (score 2):

The environment `enumerate*` starts a paragraph, with its normal indentation.

You should also add some flexibility in `itemjoin`.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{
    label = \textbf{\arabic*.},
    align = left,
    labelwidth = \parindent, 
    leftmargin = \parindent,
    style = standard,
    labelsep=4pt,
}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{enumerate*}[mode=unboxed,itemjoin = \hspace{2cm plus 2cm}]
    \item text
    \item text
    \item text
    \item text
    \item text
    \item text
    \item text
    \item text
    \item text
    \item text
\end{enumerate*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @barbarabeeton I don't think the OP is expecting that the items are aligned, unless all item texts have the same width. Otherwise `tasks` would be the choice.

Comment: hi @egreg, is there any way to put all items aligned (2 and 8, 3 and 9, 4 and 10) but ```tasks```?

Comment: @XuânDuyBảoNguyễn No.

Comment: ok thank @egreg for your info.